# Ketone prefix organic chemistry nomenclature

Tags: nomenclature, carbonyl-compounds

Is there a difference between the prefixes keto- and oxo-?

Comment: keto- $\subset$ oxo-.

Comment: oxo- is more used to just describe a c=o while keto- is used when is is specifically part of a ketone

Answer (score 2):

The prefix ‘keto’ doesn’t exist in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069).* Already in the 1979 Recommendations, the prefix ‘oxo’ is used to indicate $\ce{=O}$ when the group cannot be cited as suffix.

Nevertheless, the *[Glossary of class names of organic compounds and reactivity intermediates based on structure (IUPAC Recommendations 1995)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac199567081307)* still remembers the use of the prefix ‘keto’:

> To indicate a double-bonded oxygen that is part of a ketonic structure, the term keto is sometimes used as a prefix, but such use has been abandoned by IUPAC for naming specific compounds. A traditional use of keto is for indicating oxidation of $\ce{CHOH}$ to $\ce{C=O}$ in a parent compound that contains $\ce{OH}$ groups, such as carbohydrates. E.g. 3-ketoglucose.